# Is it possible to convert video encoding to H.264 from H.263 in cocoa or iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa

Is any samples for converting video encoding to  H.264 from H.263 in cocoa or iPhone Apis

Regards,
jeeva

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible; you could write a convertor in c. Feasible? probably not. There is no easy way to do it you'd have to write your own convertor. It would be better to [convert the videos to h.264](http://www.ogg-converter.net/h.264/convert-h.263-to-h.264.htm)